# Not enough space to cache Dataframe in memory

Tags: apache-spark

I have a requirement to read a file in my streaming application, and it is taking more time to cache this file. So I tried to replicate this in spark-shell.

Size of the file is 2.7G. I have started spark-shell with driver-memory as 6G. But its still giving me the below warnings. I believe the delay in caching the file is because of this. Any idea how to solve this.

```
 scala> val files = spark.read.parquet("/data/realtime/hierarchy")
 files: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [geo_hierarchy_base_id: string, postal_code: string ... 11 more fields]

 scala> files.cache
 res2: files.type = [geo_hierarchy_base_id: string, postal_code: string ... 11 more fields]

 scala> files.count
 [Stage 5:================>                                         (8 + 4) / 29]2019-05-10 07:19:14 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Not enough space to cache rdd_16_8 in memory! (computed 267.0 MB so far)
 2019-05-10 07:19:14 WARN  BlockManager:66 - Persisting block rdd_16_8 to disk instead.
 2019-05-10 07:19:14 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Not enough space to cache rdd_16_11 in memory! (computed 267.1 MB so far)
 2019-05-10 07:19:14 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Not enough space to cache rdd_16_9 in memory! (computed 267.0 MB so far)
 2019-05-10 07:19:14 WARN  BlockManager:66 - Persisting block rdd_16_9 to disk instead.
 2019-05-10 07:19:14 WARN  BlockManager:66 - Persisting block rdd_16_11 to disk instead.
 2019-05-10 07:19:14 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Not enough space to cache rdd_16_10 in memory! (computed 267.0 MB so far)
 2019-05-10 07:19:14 WARN  BlockManager:66 - Persisting block rdd_16_10 to disk instead.
 2019-05-10 07:19:17 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Not enough space to cache rdd_16_11 in memory! (computed 267.1 MB so far)
 2019-05-10 07:19:18 WARN  MemoryStore:66 - Not enough space to cache rdd_16_8 in memory! (computed 267.0 MB so far)
```

---

EDIT

I'm trying to cache the file in spark-shell. My input file size is 2.9GB and the driver memory for spark-shell is 10GB. I tried to cache the file. Though 10G is mentioned when launching the spark-shell, only 5.5GB is allocated for the driver(Attached the spark UI).

[image]

What I dont understand is that all the storage memory (5.3GB) and additional disk of 2.8GB is used for caching 2.9GB of file.

Could you please let me know what exactly happens when we do the cache. Why almost 3 times RAM is used.Is this because my file format is parquet and the file is exploded when reading into memory? I tried to create a text file from this just to know the file size. Text file size was around 21GB.

Thanks

Thanks.

Comment: 0.6 x 0.9 rule on memory would expain the 10gb to 5.5gb.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I see only driver under executors tab and no other details about the executors. I have to spin multiple executors as it is taking more time to read and cache a file of around 2.8 GB. Though I have given the driver memory as 16GB, its taking around 8 mins to read this. And this is causing issues as the batch interval for the program is only 5 mins. Thanks

Comment: You are correct, can only influence threads.

Comment: try spark-shell with yarn client mode. that us what i do with aws emr

Comment: The executors are threads, they and driver are part of single jvm, so you have parallelism, just to be clear

Comment: I see parquet that is normally compressed.

Comment: In any event you can cache. However Joining which I presume is your intent is for large joins not a good thing in streaming. Image millions of customere and 10k records per batch.

Comment: Yes, this would be an issue. I have around 8M records in customer file, and the number of records that I would be getting in streaming is around 11M for every 5 mins. But I dont see any other option. I cannot use broadcasting (though customer file has to be refreshed once in a month) due to the huge size which is 3GB (after snappy compression with parquet). Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: So, you take the point on compression on Parquet as being an issue that could explain.

Comment: Thanks for your time in giving the response. I tried HBase (using BulkLoad in HBaseContext) for other different streaming project. Had some issues with it. So I tried to load it (through hive) in spark and refresh the DF every day at a specific time. But for this project, I cannot use HBase as this streaming job is run only on a single server (running it as local without YARN as hadoop is not required for this) which reads from a folder. So cannot use HBase. Thanks.

Comment: Point was more a lkp to hbase

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: For now, am just trying to do the joins as broadcasting doesnt work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer to minimize the memory consumption in spark.